# Build Automation TFS ANT

Tags: java, ant, tfs

I am trying to create TFS ANT build script.When getting the resource for TFS from ant : "com/teamprise/ant/antlib.xml". It is not able to load the jar. I understand from the search that ,this antlib.xml is no more supported. Can any body suggest me which resource to look for to get the access of command line tfs commands in my ant script.

Following is the snippet of the code:

```
<path id= "tfsant.classpath" >
                <fileset dir= "${env.ANT_HOME}/lib" >
                        <include name= "*teamprise-ant*.jar" />
                </fileset>
        </path>`enter code here`


        <typedef resource="com/teamprise/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="tfsant.classpath" />

<exec executable="tf">
                    <arg value="checkout"/>
                    <arg value="${tfsroot}/temp/BUILD_${build.number}"/>
                    <arg value="${workdir}"/>
                </exec>
```

Comment: Don't do this. your ant build file is part of the source code - it doesn't checkout the source code.  You have a chicken and egg problem here.  You want your build server (travis, drone, jenkins, etc...) to check out the source and then run your ant script.  If for some reason you want to script checkout out the source, ant is a terrible choice.  Look into python, ruby or even a bat file.

Comment: I have heard of jenkins. So , we need to integrate jenkins ,tfs and ant together? Can you suggest me some link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx) on your machine. This will install the TF Command-Line utility. Configure the environment variable "Path" for tf.exe, then you can access to tf command directly from your ANT script.

Comment: Hi Eddie, I downloaded the file from the location specified and extracted it to my local drive. Inside D:\Preethi\Softwares\TEE-CLC-12.0.2 ,I can see tf.cmd and tf.txt . Where do we get the tf.exe? Is there something ,which I am missing? or should I have to set the Path="D:\Preethi\Softwares\TEE-CLC-12.0.2"?

Comment: @PreethiJha Did you set the"Path" variable so that it can be access directly without the entity path? A link for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html